# Why was there no Stan Lee cameo in Deadpool 2?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, cameo, stan-lee, deadpool-2

Stan Lee didn't appear in Deadpool 2. Is there a public reason for this?

He did appear in the first installment, so Deadpool being Deadpool probably isn't it.

Comment: he did appear in the teaser of deadpool2, that could be the reason

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From this [screenrant article](https://screenrant.com/deadpool-2-stan-lee-cameo/):

> For Deadpool 2, the Stan Lee cameo is more in line with those of the
>   Marvel shows on Netflix than his show-stopping MCU appearances.
>   Indeed, just his famous face appears rather than Stan "The Man"
>   himself. In this case, it isn't a photograph or poster but a graffiti
>   portrait painted on the side of a building; Stan's portrait can be
>   seen just as Domino comes in for her parachute landing after the rest
>   of X-Force has met their untimely (if hilarious) ends. It's a
>   blink-and-you'll-miss-it moment, making this appearance of Lee more of
>   an Easter egg than a true cameo.

So he was in there, but a bit more difficult to spot than the usual, actually filmed cameos.

EDIT: Managed to find a screengrab - bit blurry but Stan's mural is top right and the mildly blurry person toward the lower part of the picture is Domino:

[image: Domino parachutes past Stan Lee in Deadpool 2]

Comment: Huh, must've missed that. Is there any information on why they did that? Deadpool 1 did have a filmed cameo.

Comment: Maybe because he was in Deadpool 2 trailer?

Comment: @JAD I think he don't like flying and report say MCU even do his cameo shot in bulks, so maybe Fox has to do same and he did had real cameo in Deadpool2 promotional clip for logon